# Mimicking UITableView layout using UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: swift, uitableview, layout, uicollectionview

I have been trying to mimic an UITableView layout using UICollectionView. So far I have gotten this:

```
class TableViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override init() {
        super.init()

        minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        minimumLineSpacing = 6
        scrollDirection = .vertical

        estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        let currentBounds = collectionView?.bounds ?? .zero
        return newBounds.width != currentBounds.width
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else { return [] }

        let sectionInsets: CGFloat = sectionInset.left + sectionInset.right
        let contentInsets: CGFloat = (collectionView?.contentInset.left ?? 0) + (collectionView?.contentInset.right ?? 0)

        for attribute in attributes where attribute.frame.intersects(rect) {
            attribute.size.width = collectionView!.readableContentGuide.layoutFrame.width - sectionInsets - contentInsets
        }

        return attributes
    }
}
```

Which works pretty great until I rotate the device from landscape to portrait, after that the layout hangs saying that the cell is wider than the actual item size.

Am I missing something trivial here? I don't see any glaring problems standing out. The layout is pretty simple just UILabels with an underdetermine amount of text. They can be seen in here

## Portrait

[image: Portrait]

## Landscape

[image: Landscape]

## Error after portrait from landscape

[image: Error]

Comment: Can you check what your `shouldInvalidateLayout` returns when this error happens? It should return `true`.

Comment: it does return true